# Issue with NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string in my header file named

```
NSString *enemy;
```

In implementation file i'm initializing that string from a plist file like this

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSDictionary *level_data = [data objectForKey:[@"Level" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", level]];

enemy = [level_data objectForKey:@"enemy"];
```

and then this "enemy" string, when i use it in method like this

```
-(void) addEnemy{
    if([enemy isEqualToString:@"Ostrich"]){
        [some_Obj valueCalc:t];
    }
}
```

it works fine for the first call to that "addEnemy" method but when i call this method again the string "enemy" throws an Exception. After debugging i came to know that at second call to the method "addEnemy" the string "enemy" shows "Variable is not NSString" in debugger.

but if i initialize "enemy" like this

```
enemy = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[level_data objectForKey:@"enemy"]];
```

then it works quite fine.

Can anyone tell me why the above mentioned problem occurs?

Comment: @KevinBallard probably not. Under ARC this is not very likely to happen.

Comment: What is the full error message when the app crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you've provided isn't sufficient to say exactly what's wrong, but it sounds like the problem is that `enemy` is being deallocated before `-addEnemy` is called. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble by using `@property` accessors instead of setting and accessing instance variables directly.

In your header file:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *enemy;

@end
```

In your implementation (.m) file:

```
- (void)initializationMethod // Don't know what this really is in your code
{
    // get level_data from plist
    self.enemy = [level_data objectForKey:@"enemy"];
}

// Then in -addEnemy:
- (void)addEnemy
{
    if([self.enemy isEqualToString:@"Ostrich"])
    {
        [some_Obj valueCalc:t];
    }
}

// If (and only if) you're not using ARC, you need this. But, really you should use ARC.
- (void)dealloc
{
     [_enemy release];
     [super release];
}
```

This way, the synthesized setter method for the @property takes care of retaining `enemy` for you so it's not deallocated out from under you. You also really ought to [read up](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) on Objective-C Memory Management, particularly if you're not going to use ARC. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14904463/344733) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14903920/344733) for some more reasons why it's a good idea to use accessor methods.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a string in my header file named
>
> NSString *enemy;

This states this is an iVar.

You need to have a @property.
And you must use `strong` in ARC or `retain` in MRC.

As everytime is getting released and new instance is created.

Comment: in ARC `strong` is default, you don't have to do a thing

Comment: you don't need to have a property, you can have an ivar as well, the default qualifier is still `strong`.

Comment: But you don't know where in the header file that declaration is. If it's in the wrong spot (we don't know yet), it could be a global, not an ivar.

Answer (score 0):

Declare in .h file and add properties to this variable and further information read [this document](http://cagt.bu.edu/w/images/b/b6/Objective-C_Programming_Language.pdf).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *enemy;
```

I think this is helpful to you.